# How do I dynamically adjust the y position of a graph regardless of monitor resolution?

Tags: c#, winforms, graph

I have been designing a winform program that graphs the activity of switches in a 24 hour period. I had everything positioned well on my surface pro, where each minute was equal to a pixel on the y axis. for example, the center panel was sized at 1440 pixels which there are 1440 minutes in 24 hours. See image 1. I have now gone to a different sized monitor and all my y positions have been thrown out due to center panel being resized to 862. I'm wondering if there is a way to manage this issue without having to fix the height of the program to fit a generic screen. e.g 720 pixel center panal and display every 2 minute intervals instead of 1.

[Image of graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhlQf.png)

[Code for drawing rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaeLh.png)

I am hoping to upscale the center panel to plot 1min increments regardless of monitor size.

Comment: You should almost never depend on the exact pixel resolution. You need to calculate how many pixels 1min represents on whatever size your panel is, or how long time 1 pixel represents.

Comment: Hard to tell. You are using some magic numbers and numbers coming from somewhere directly used for pixel distances. Typically that won't work. That numbers need to be adjusted to the actual dpi settings on the monitor you use. As you say you designed that on "surface pro" have you ignored the designer warning that tells you have a dpi setting other then 100%? In that case there are more problems ahead of you.